# iPhone 6 shows a distorted launch screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin app, created with VS 2017 with the latest Xamarin version for VS 2017.

On all iPhones younger than iPhone 6, the launchscreen is correct. ONLY on iPhone 6, the app starts with its splash screen distorted to an oval shape. The resolution was at first 640*1136 but it seems, the iPhone6 scales it to 640 x 960. So I changed the resolution to 640 x 960 px. Still the oval.

What is the correct resolution?

- [distorted rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weyIO.png)
- [original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQIvU.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! The information you provided won't be enough to diagnose your problem. Please provide code snippets or screenshots of how you are implementing the splash screen. Though it seems like you might have an issue with auto layout

Comment: Are you using static launch images or a storyboard for your launch screen?

Comment: I use the image.xcassets via Visual Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct resolution of IPhone 6 is `750 x 1334`, you can check the resolution of different device [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html).

If you use `image.xcassets` via Visual Studio, just put the image with correct size into the corresponding image set, there is size above each image like 320*48, 640* 960... here is the screenshot:

[image]